# php - Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted when using fopen

Tags: php, database, memory, fopen

I have code similar to the following:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
$dates = Array('14-JUL-14','13-JUL-14','12-JUL-14', ...etc )
$filename = '/home/me/query-output_all.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($dates as $currday) {
    $query = "--sql query with large result set";

    //perform query
    $rows = $dbo->query($dbh,$query); //set earlier. dbh = oci_connect()

    //add rows to file
    foreach ($rows as $value) {
        //add date key to $value
        array_unshift($value, $currday);
        fputcsv($fp, $value);
    }
}
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

I am getting the following error when my $dates array contains 90 or so dates:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted
```

After researching, I believe that this is caused by the $fp variable becoming too large. Is there a way that I can write to a file, like above, without have to worry about this size limiation? (note - increasing memory_limit is a temporary fix, but not long term, considering that it's possible that I will be querying to 10+ gigabytes of total data at some point.)

Comment: `$fp` is just a file handle. it does get "too large". probably your `$value` array is getting too large.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not understanding the above comments - I read the foreach loop as: for each row in results set, use that row as a value array (looks something like Array(['col1']->'val1',['col2']->'val2'...) ). Then, add $currday to the front of $value. Then, put $value in $fp as csv. So when does $value grow in size?

Comment: Try cloning the `$currday` e.g `$csv_insert = $currday` and then add to it with `array_unshift($value, $csv_insert);` followed by `fputcsv($fp, $csv_insert);` then `unset($csv_insert)` it on `$currday` iteration... sorry not somewhere I can test then answer :(

Comment: That seems like a strange thing to try - is there some quirk with php that causes memory allocation to accumulate for variables like $currday? Anyways - I added `unset($value);` to `foreach ($rows as $value) {` and `unset($currday); unset($rows); unset($query);` to the bottom of `foreach ($dates as $currday) {`. It appears to work now. I imagine that php was not deallocating the memory for these variables, and `unset()` is now forcing it to. Thanks for the help :)